# Connect remotely to Linode mysql server

Tags: mysql, remote-access, linode

I'm trying to connect remotely to a mysql server on Linode.

I have cPanel access to the server but when I attempt to access remotely from another server (e.g. my aws server) I get "Host xxx is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

I added the ip and domain name of my aws server to the Linode "Remote MySQL" but still get above message.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank

Comment: show if the **HOST** is enabled for this user **SELECT * FROM mysql.user ;**

Comment: Thanks Bernd!  Although, I wonder if the access doesn't have remote access.  When I execute the query via phpMyAdmin I'm getting "SELECT command denied to user 'myuseid'@'localhost' for table 'user'"

Comment: which client do you use to connect remotely ?

Comment: I tried from one of my other servers (ubuntu) using mysql and Toad (Toad Edge); from shell I use "mysql -u username -ppassword -h domainname" (where mysql server is hosted)

Comment: i have found it. you can only access your db local or you use a tunnel. Please read this: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/create-an-ssh-tunnel-for-mysql-remote-access/ . you can also use ssh (on linux) to create a tunnel

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but for some reason can't connect...getting "Network error: connection refused".  I wonder for putty if I'm using the correct domain/ip for step 4. I logged into mysql server cPanel and used the "Shared IP Address".   I also tried using my domain for step 4 and still get Network Error :-(.  It doesn't mention in the instructions you sent but wonder if I need to use public/private key

Comment: Its possible ssh isn't running. I'll contact them.  Thanks!